# Error: listen EACCES: permission denied on windows

Tags: node.js

Good day,

I have been trying to get an IPC server working for child processes to communicate with each other. I followed this SO answer ([Communication between child processes in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624671/communication-between-child-processes-in-node-js)) to try creating an IPC server between two child processes. However, I get this error on windows:

```
PS F:\Node Projects\communication-between-child-process-node-js> node parent
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied F:\Node Projects\communication-between-child-process-node-js/sibling.sock
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1314:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1379:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1476:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Node Projects\communication-between-child-process-node-js\parent.js:17:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1358:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: 'F:\\Node Projects\\communication-between-child-process-node-js/sibling.sock',
  port: -1
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have everything set up the way it was in that SO answer. I think it's a windows issue but does anyone know how to give permission to use the socket?

Comment: Are you sure you're using a valid port number? Also, you can try trstarting WinNAT by opening Powershell as admin and running `net stop winnat` then `net start winnat`.

Comment: @Lissy93 they're not listening on a port but on a socket file. My guess is that the issue has to do with using (Unix-style) forward slashes in the socket file path, instead of (Windows-style) backward slashes.

Comment: @robertklep yes that's right, I am using a socket file instead of a local net server. I already interact with files using both slashes and it works alright. But what I can do right now is try making the whole thing a string and use the same slashes throughout the path.

Comment: @robertklep I have tried using forward slashes and back slashes throughout the whole path, makes no difference to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Windows, [the following documentation is relevant](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#identifying-paths-for-ipc-connections):

> On Windows, the local domain is implemented using a named pipe. The path must refer to an entry in `\\?\pipe\` or `\\.\pipe\`. Any characters are permitted, but the latter may do some processing of pipe names, such as resolving `..` sequences. Despite how it might look, the pipe namespace is flat. Pipes will not persist. They are removed when the last reference to them is closed. Unlike Unix domain sockets, Windows will close and remove the pipe when the owning process exits.

The documentation also shows an example on how to create a socket file path:

```
path.join('\\\\?\\pipe', process.cwd(), 'myctl')
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check out the documentation you linked!